# Configuring Azure SQL Server firewall - is allowing all IP's to connect a red flag?

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I just created my first Azure SQL Server and Database and now am trying to configure the firewall so that my web application can connect and make changes to the single database on the server.

I see that you can allow all clients to connect by allowing a rule such:
[image]

However is this bad practice? I see my Client IP address is listed in the Azure portal can I get clarification that I should allow just that single IP address access for now, and then later when I publish my web application to Azure I will be given an IP address of where that web app lives and only restrict access to that (assuming that people can only make database changes through my front end application).

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is bad practice.  There are other layers they'd have to get through (e.g., the server login), but this opens the front door and allows anyone to pick away at it at their leisure.

If you have a web server hosting your web application on some server (which you must be), whitelist that server's IP address (and perhaps your own, for development/admin purposes), but allowing all IPs is not considered good practice, no.

One particular case where you may really want to allow this is if you are distributing a desktop application to unknown clients that must connect to the backend.  It becomes extremely enticing at that point, but even so, the recommended practice (or at least, my recommended practice) would be to utilize a web service that will accept an application registration upon startup of the app, register the client IP temporarily through that, and then have a background server (think WebJobs) that will flush the firewall rules say, every night or so (or for a more elaborate setup, accept the registration with a timeout and use a continuous WebJob to poll for the timeout and refresh/revoke as necessary)

Comment: @Pipeline Glad to help.  Remember that security is comprised of many layers, and for full effectiveness they should all be as restricted as reasonable.  While this in itself wouldn't necessarily allow people to easily hack your database, it's one less layer they'd have to go through!

Comment: An azure app service has a dynamc ip address - any way to either update the firewall when the ip changes, or have azure specifically allow this app service? I'm currently simply using a connectionstring with user/pw to access the db.